# Datatables pagination not responding as expected

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, datatables

I know there are lots of simliar questions out there, but I believe my scenario is different.

Using debug.datatables.net (the bookmark)

I noted the following response from my server.

```
{
    "sEcho": 1,
    "iTotalRecords": 234,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": 10,
    "aaData": [
...10 data ...
    ]
}
```

However, I only get 1 page of results, resulting in no ajax calls whenever I click any pagination button.

Here's my script

```
<script>
    $('#bookings_listing').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "{{ path('admin_booking_datatable') }}",
        "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bPaginate": true
    });
</script>
```

According to the documents, pagination is generated by taking

```
(iTotalDisplayRecords - iTotalRecords)/resultsPerPage
```

which, in reference to the data I've given back, should generate the correct paginations. Am I getting this wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/15587/issues-with-pagination-with-server-side-datasource

```
"iTotalDisplayRecords":10
```

> That's wrong.

To others who faced similar issues, note that **`iTotalDisplayRecords`** is not to be the number of results displayed per page. It's meant to be the total number of records after your database is filtered.